# How to reduce bundle size Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, android-app-bundle

What are some tips to reduce Android App Bundle size in Unity?

Is there any way to do it in less than 10MB?

I have 33.4MB of apk. Here is the Editor Log:

```
Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category (Percentages based on user generated assets only):
Textures               1.4 mb    6.8% 
Meshes                 0.0 kb    0.0% 
Animations             102.1 kb  0.5% 
Sounds                 152.2 kb  0.7% 
Shaders                130.5 kb  0.6% 
Other Assets           1.8 mb    9.0% 
Levels                 1.9 mb    9.5% 
Scripts                1.0 mb    5.2% 
Included DLLs          13.3 mb   66.4% 
File headers           270.7 kb  1.3% 
Total User Assets      20.0 mb   100.0% 
Complete build size    109.4 mb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tips

In order to reduce APK or App Bundle size for Android in Unity, here is some tips:

- Compress images and texture with ETC (ETC or ETC2) or DXT compression (Crunched RGBA for transparent images, RGB for solid background)
- Compress audio files (Compressed in Memory)
- Remove unused packages from Package Manager
- Remove unused plugins from Assets
- Reduce files in Resources from Assets

More info here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html

### AssetBundle

I prefer to use a Bundle of resources called AssetBundle. It's quite easy to create, then you upload it on a public server. At the end, in your Unity project you have to download it, unpack and then use it.

All the resources in the AssetsBundle can be delete from the project. This solution is used for Google Instant App for Unity.

More info here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html

Comment: Why ETC compression doesn't work? I put 0% quality for an image, but it still has the same size.

Comment: Talking about `RGB/A Crunched ETC/DXT`, image's width/height must be multiple of 4 as said in the docs: _Only textures with width/height being multiple of 4 can be compressed to Crunch format_.  

You should resize images so that widths and heights are multiple of 4. Otherwise use a non-crunched compression